# Get Entire Page Source in Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to get page source together with doctype, head and body.

window.content.document is document but I can't collect anything except innerHTML which does not include doctype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOCTYPE isn't included because it isn't a child of the document element, it's rather a direct child of the document itself. You can serialize the entire document using XML serializer however:

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
alert(serializer.serializeToString(window.content.document));
```

This will do an XML serialization - not quite the same thing as HTML. If that's a problem you can go through the `window.content.document.childNodes` collection and get `node.innerHTML` for the element nodes (`node.nodeType == 1`), only use `XMLSerializer` on the rest of them. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer for more info.

Comment: Interesting. Only difference is that I get <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> instead <html>, everithing else is identical. Thanks.